# Reduce time when Mongo database is called for the first time in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a website where you can click on the URL to access a page. To display datas in this new page, I verify if there is also this URL in the database. If it's the same, the results (realtives to the URL) are displayed and the page appears.

When it's the first time that the Mongo database is called, it's quite long (several seconds for a 35MB database) and I'd like to reduce this time.

I use Mlab, Express and Mongoose.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Its called cold boot, It's because Mlab database is on sleep mode for free version, it wakes when required, they have paid plan that doens't sleep VM

Comment: I never thought of that, I didn't know it was like that with Mlab

Comment: But I read that MongoDB bought Mlab so I'm looking for infos on this cold boot thing with Atlas.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your question is just retrieving the URL. If so:

1. Migrate from Mlab to Atlas, use the free version, it's still faster.
2. Index the field for URL for better query.

I don't know precisely how your DB looks like, but there are a lot of good strategies by the official mongoDB team for faster query and better indexing:

Query optimization - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/
Index strategy - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Another user thinks it's caused by cold boot and my free plan. I'm going to see how does it work with Atlas